# Upgrading iOS apps from 32 Bit to 64 Bit

Tags: ios, iphone

I have developed an iOS enterprise app long way back on old Xcode version (32 bit architecture). Currently since Apple has launched iOS 10, the devices which have upgraded their versions are giving a notification that this app will slower down the device performance.
In this case how should I resolve this issue, should I upgrade it to 64 bit architecture?
If I overlook this issue will it be of any problem in long run, If yes than please share the method to resolve this.
Any suggestions will really be helpful.

Comment: you just need to recompile/resubmit your projects with the latest SDK (updating for that) and recommended project settings (by Xcode as default), and that will be good enough – also don't forget to conform your project the latest review guidelines as well for the successful approval.

Answer (score 3):

Open your app in updated `Xcode` then select your Project goto `Build Settings` tab and in `Architectures` add `Valid Architectures` as `arm64`,`armv7` and `armv7s`. 
In `Architectures` select `Standard architecutres`

Hope, it helps.

Comment: Be sure to select sub tab “All” after clicking “Build Settings.” Otherwise you won’t see the “Architectures” section.